# How do Firebase communicate with clients?

Tags: security, firebase, protocols

I'm a student in Republic of Korea. My major is Information security.
I'm doing a project that is using Firebase. and I'm writing a report.
However, I don't know how Firebase library communicate with clients application(iOS, Android, Web).
For example... Firebase use HTTPS, SSH or a token(like JWT).
And I want to know If that’s safe or not when a clients application send inputted informations to Firebase.

My English level is not good. so I don't know I well wrote. XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All communication between the Firebase SDK and the server is safely encrypted, regardless of the type of channel used.  This is true on any platform where SDKs are provided.  For Authentication, JWT is used.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you talk to me about Firebase SDK use security protocols or encrypt algorithms?